# Accessing an Objects instance constructor for cloning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TLDR: Are there any pitfalls in using this.constructor(props) in a class method to duplicate that class?

I have a use case where defining class models for entities proves quite useful for management and processing throughout a complex system.

These entity model classes all require a set of common methods.

I do not wish to duplicate code across multiple entity model classes. I am exploring the use of a BaseEntityModel class which can be extended by all other model classes requiring the common functionality.

One of these methods is a `clone()` method, which provides a deep clone of the object as the ExtendedEntityModel type.

`clone()` will be declared on the BaseEntityModel class. I want to preserve the class name and properties when calling clone from a ExtendedEntityModel object which has extended BaseEntityModel class.

I need a way of creating a new instance of a ExtendedEntityModel through the BaseEntityModel without having to explicitly know what it is when calling `clone()`. In otherwords, I wanted to avoid using `new ParentClassEntity()` because the BaseEntityModel methods need to work for all extensions of it.

I did some searching but could not find much on this pattern. After some tinkering, I found that calling `this.constructor(props)` does exactly what I want. See below class, and `clone()` function

BaseEntityModel.js

```
class BaseEntityModel {
  constructor({ entityType, dataKeys }) {
    this.entityType = entityType;
    this.dataKeys = dataKeys;
  }

 /**
  * Provide deep clone of self, Preserving extended class properties
  */
  clone() {
     return new this.constructor(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this))); //<-- here, this.constructor
   };
}
```

ExtendedModel.js

```
class ExtendedModel extends BaseEntityModel {

    constructor({param1, param2} : ExtendedModel) {
        super({ entityType, dataKeys });
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

}
```

and then usage

```
var extendedModel1 = new ExtendedModel({param1, param2};
var clonedExtendedModel = extendedModel1.clone(); //returns a cloned version and of type ExtendedModel
```

I cannot find much on calling `this.constructor`. Can anyone provide some insight into why this might be a bad choice, or confirm that this is not a javascript bomb waiting to go off?

See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-fog-68jxq?file=/src/App.js) of working implementation

Comment: `return this.constructor(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this)));` is problematic. Constructors  are called with `new` keyword.

Comment: updated to `return new  this.constructor(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this)));`